# Google Maps geocode addressess with custom labels?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been banging my head against my desk for the past day or so and cannot figure this out. Whenever markers are added to my map they randomly generate their labels. This would be fine, but there is PHP code is called on the page that shows the locations in a listed order. This list has to match the markers. I would like to use the number in the location array as my label, but no matter what I try I cannot get label: locations[i][2] (or any variation) to work.

I tried adding a variable that is equal to locations[i][2] in the for loop, but it just stores and displays the last number when the variable is called in the marker function.

Hope this makes sense.

```
  var locations = [
  ['text','address1','1'], 
  ['text','address2','2'],
  ];

var labels = '123456789';
var labelIndex = 0;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.3509665,-81.6881185),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  disableDefaultUI: true
});

var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
trafficLayer.setMap(map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  geocodeAddress(locations[i]);
}

function geocodeAddress(location) {
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location[1]}, function(results, status) {
//alert(status);
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

  //alert(results[0].geometry.location);
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  createMarker(results[0].geometry.location,location[0]+"<br>"+location[1]);
}
else
{
  alert("some problem in geocode" + status);
}
 }); 
}

function createMarker(latlng,html){
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
map: map,
label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
}); 

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { 
infowindow.setContent(html);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() { 
infowindow.close();
});

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the updated functions, I have added a 3rd variable for `createMarker` called `label` where I pass `location[2]` to this variable.

```
function geocodeAddress(location) {
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location[1]}, function(results, status) {
//alert(status);
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

  //alert(results[0].geometry.location);
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  createMarker(results[0].geometry.location,location[0]+"<br>"+location[1],location[2]);
}
else
{
  alert("some problem in geocode" + status);
}
 }); 
}

function createMarker(latlng,html,label){
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng,
map: map,
label: label
});
```

Comment: Holy crap. I can't believe it would have been that easy. I feel dumb now.

THANKS!!!